# Modify LightOpenId to work via popup

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, openid

I'm currently using `lightopenid` - http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/ to log in users, by default it works by redirecting the current page to the login page and then back to a successful/error page on completion. This works okay but it means the user must briefly leave the website.

I'm trying to modify it to work so that when a user clicks one of the login buttons it will open the login in a popup window instead of redirect, this means the user would never need to leave the site and would be an improvement. The following is an example of the functionality I am trying to achieve: http://openid-demo.appspot.com/

At the moment it's all done in php apart from the javascript that opens the openId url in the popup window but this doesn't function correct as I'm not sure how to pass data between the main window and the popup after the user has tried to login in the popup or even close the popup.

**Pseudo Code Aim:**

1. User navigates to Log In page
2. User selects Google/Yahoo/OpenId
3. Popup window opens
4. User enter details
5. On Success popup window is closed and main windows redirects to member area

Are there OpenId libraries as simple as lightopenid with this popup feature or is the best way to create javascript so that both windows can communicate? My only issue with this is will the data passed between the two be safe? All this member login functionality would be carried out with https only.

Comment: Quick pre-note: people don't like popups, and most have them blocked -- though this might get through some user's blockers since it was initiated. More related to your question, take a look at the `window.opener` property for your popup.